# Toolbar группирует иконки

Tags: java, android

Добрый день добавил 3 иконки в toolbar он сгруппировал их в мен. тоесть 1 иконка есть другая кионка группировки .но стоит сделать 2 иконки то обе видны .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_load"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="load"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_file"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_equal"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_equal"
        android:orderInCategory="3"

        android:title="equal"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sync"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="sync"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">

    </item>




</menu>
```

Как сделать чтоб показывал только иконки без групировки

Answer (score 3):

Такое поведение обусловлено

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

что значит "отображать в тулбаре, если есть место. Иначе - спрятать за 3 точками"

Вам надо заменить на

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

в этом случае будут отображены все элементы меню.